# Access item in ListField/EmbeddedDocumentListField by using __raw__ in MongoEngine

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I use mongoengine 0.15.0. In my Inventory Models, there is an ListField 'fruit' that contains EmbeddedDocumentField 'EmbedFruit'. Each EmbedFruit item has 'color' field. I want to access the first item in the ListField.

Can I achieve it by:

```
result_object = Inventory.objects(__raw__={
    'fruit.0.color': 'red',
}).first()
```

Comment: Did you try the `__` syntax? Or did you just presume it would not work?

Comment: I will try __ syntax, thanks for reminder!

Comment: I have tried result_object = Inventory.objects( fruit__0__color='red').first()

Comment: Ahh, you mean you only want **that item** from the list field. MongoEngine does not support that. You actually need to use the raw `_collection` and project the specified index. Should be an example around here somewhere. The question I linked you to before actually showed this with the `$` in projection. And of course there is an answer here, since I did answer this some time ago.

Comment: In your case that can even be `FaultReport._get_collection().find({ 'fruit.0.color': 'red' }, { 'fruit.0': 1 })` since the `$` becomes redundant when you already know you want the `0` index returned.

Comment: @Neil Lunn  What I want is an Inventory item which satisfy the requirement: 'the field 'color' of the first item of EmbeddedDocumentField 'fruit' is equal to 'red'

Comment: So that's what you have been given. Read the linked answer. Read the included link to the Github issue on MongoEngine and other notes as to why "projections" are not supported with the object model.

Comment: @Neil Lunn Sounds good. Can I use 'find' API in mongoengine? I didn't found it in documentation.